# Supplied javaHome must be a valid directory. You supplied: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_241

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic5

I got this error message when I build ionic cordova for android:

> Supplied javaHome must be a valid directory. You supplied: C:\Program
> Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_241

The problem is that path is different from what I have JAVA_HOME variable:

[image]

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Open the `CMD` Command Prompt using Administrator privilege and check the value of the JAVA_HOME variable:

```
echo %JAVA_HOME%
```

The result should be the path to the JDK installation:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202
```

So, if the java version is a different version, you can set the correct one:

```
setx -m JAVA_HOME "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_241"
setx -m PATH "%PATH%;%JAVA_HOME%\bin";
```

Just do adjusts on the Java version as you need to correct the differences. Be sure you have the installed version that you are trying to set up.

The another solution is to clean the Gradle build cache.

```
gradlew cleanBuildCache
```

Comment: echo %JAVA_HOME%  result is C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202

Comment: Please, go to the java directory C:\Program Files\Java\ and take a look at the Java versions over there. I think you can have more than one Java versions installed in your computer. If you find another version, use the command above to set up its version. If not found another version, go to the Windows global variables and set up the correct version you have installed in your computer. Good luck bro!

Comment: I already removed the other versions and changed Windows global variables and restarted my pc.

Comment: I have updated the answer with a command to clean the Gradle build.

Comment: Cleaning gradle did not help.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: download and install new jdk on different location and update the JAVA_HOME path.

Step 2: make sure to add bin folder path under path Environment variable, refer below picture.

[image: add marked snippet under path (which is under system variable)]

Comment: The problem is not with jdk, it's somewhere in ionic compiler as it still see the old home_path before updated.